# Deploying a typescript node.js to Azure Web App - getting 'service unavailable' error

Tags: node.js, azure, typescript, npm, azure-web-app-service

I uploaded a react-redux app to a web app service on azure using VSCode's 'Azure App Services' extension, basically a clone of this repo: https://github.com/rokoroku/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate

When I visit the URL the app doesn't load and it's followed by 'service unavaiable' after a while.

I think my issue is to do with my npm start command but not sure..

> "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --inline --watch"

How does Azure deploy an uploaded node.js web app?

Comment: The start command is meant for development, not deployment

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `typescript` dependency from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` in `package.json`

Comment: While this may be the answer, providing more information as to way this may be would be helpful to the poster and others that may look at this post for help.